# Is This even possible to write

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm at the point where I think I should give up on this project. I have hit dead ends at every attempt.

The basic concept is that I have an INI file that is read by my main page. My main page has two list boxes that get the option information from the INI file using php. When An option is selected in list box one, I call an on change java function that should change list box two.

I thought I could do this by having PHP create all the list boxes from the ini first, and have them set to display:none. Then the Javascript would turn the display to Block, depending on the option selection in list box one.

The problem I keep running into is Javascript not able to read directly from the INI, and PHP cannot do onclick events unless the whole page reloads.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Not the best title ever.

Comment: can we see some code? what have u tried so far?

Comment: Either embed all necessary data into the page so Javascript can show it, or learn about AJAX.

Comment: Just return the appropriate box contents via your PHP script...

Comment: In software all things are possible

Comment: I found a trick that I am using solely with PHP and Javascript, AJax will come in due time. Thanks Brad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do; you just need to use AJAX techniques.  Your javascript captures the events, then sends a request to your PHP via XMLHttpRequest.  PHP reads the INI and echos the information, which javascript captures in its responseText and then updates the interface accordingly.

I highly recommend you research AJAX.  It's good stuff.

Comment: I would like to suggest looking into jQuery before writing your own AJAX functions.

Comment: @Ryan I would suggest understanding how things work first before using abstraction libraries.